# Imgur API - Get 400 error when registering an application

Tags: imgur

I try to register an application, at this [webpage](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient), to upload some images to imgur.

After I select the "OAuth 2 authorization without a callback URL", enter the email, and submit the form, I will get the 400 error. As shown in the picture.

[image: register an applicationat the webpage]

[image: 400 error after form submit]

Why don't I get the successful message but the error one? Are there limits for a new user?

I see the help page at the [imgur.com](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/204956796-API), and it recommends to post the question about api in here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done (i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina Thank you for the notice. I have updated the question. There is no code sample for all the operations on the [webpage](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient).